# Making multiple convex hulls in a GeoDataFrame based on a categorical attribute in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

Suppose I have a GeoDataFrame as follows:

```
    | cat    | geom
----+--------+-------------
  0 | 0      | POINT(0, 0)
  1 | 0      | POINT(0, 1)
  2 | 0      | POINT(1, 1)
  3 | 0      | POINT(1, 0)
  4 | 1      | POINT(5, 5)
  5 | 1      | POINT(5, 6)
  6 | 1      | POINT(6, 6)
  7 | 1      | POINT(6, 5)
```

I want to make a GeoDataFrame with convex hulls for the point geometries for each category, while retaining the `cat` column to indicate which category the hull corresponds to. Can I do this in one line? I was thinking something like:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = ...
gpd.tools.collect(gdf.groupby(gdf["cat"])[gdf.geometry.name]).convexhull
```

I know that this isn't right but I'm not sure about the grouping syntax required to achieve such a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gdf.dissolve("cat").convex_hull` gives what you want. In this case, it converts `cat` column as index column. And `convex_hull` changes name of `"geometry"` column to `0` (zero). I don't know why, maybe it is a bug.

Therefore, you can use this: `gdf.dissolve("cat").convex_hull.reset_index().set_geometry(0)`

Result  (I used `5`, `6` as `cat` values):

```
    | cat    | 0
----+--------+------------
  0 | 5      | POLYGON(... -> Convex hull
  1 | 6      | POLYGON(...
```

I use geopandas 0.8.1.